# Stability of LEDs from thermal runaway

Tags: led, thermal

I'm talking about LED lights which are used to light homes from main wall supply
[230V] here.

If I developed a LED driver and its heat sink, is there is a way to measure its 
stability against thermal runaway? I mean to calculate whether the heat sink is enough or
the protection mechanism of the driver is enough.

What kind of machines are there to collect these data and measure the integrity in industry
assembly lines? What data should I collect and what model should be used?

I also want to know the benchmarks and standards on thermal stability used in industry.

Comment: LEDs in serious applications should (must) be driven in constant current mode. There is then no prospect of "runaway". The issue then is whether the LED die temperature is maintained at an acceptable level. Reputable LED manufacturers provide a very large body of data re thermal aspects.

Comment: Heat sinking is the main area of attention and this is a well understood discipline. Once designed an LED mounting system will generally work as designed if manufactured correctly. LEDs are usually operated substantially below levels where active temperature management is required  (ie altering power to control temperature is not a usual design practice).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LEDs in serious applications should (must) be driven in constant current mode.
There is then no prospect of "runaway".

The issue then is whether the LED die temperature is maintained at an acceptable level.   Reputable LED manufacturers provide a very large body of data re thermal aspects.

Heat sinking is the main area of attention and this is a well understood discipline. Once designed an LED mounting system will generally work as designed if manufactured correctly. LEDs are usually operated substantially below levels where active temperature management is required (ie altering power to control temperature is not a usual design practice).

..... Luxeon [Thermal design using power light sources](http://www.led-tech.de/produkt-pdf/luxeon/luxeon_thermal_design_guide.pdf)
.......... and [LUXEON Thermal Management Capabilities](http://www.philipslumileds.com/technology/thermal)

...Cypress - [Thermal Design Considerations for High Power LED Systems](http://www.cypress.com/?docID=9202)

.........ECN [LED thermal design](http://www.ecnmag.com/articles/2010/08/led-thermal-design-challenges-tips-and-techniques)

....Digikey [Practical LED thermal design](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/practical-led-thermal-design)

Wikipedia [Thermal_management_of_high-power_LEDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_management_of_high-power_LEDs)

Example  only - [heatsinks](http://www.led-heatsink.com/?gclid=CNamv5u34LkCFc3CpAodESkA5Q)

---

CFD model of thermal transfer from an LED bulb.
See Wikipedia reference above for GIF animation of this.

[image]